Office 365 document background is black, whatever the Theme settings
So my kids have somehow changed the default document background in all office apps (Word, Excel, Outlook, ...) to black. It is only the page itself, or the cells in Excel that are black, the menu etc is normal theme color. I have checked all Theme settings, but everything seems normal.
I can individually change the page from "no color" to "white". But that simply changes it for a single document.
General settings are ok, no Dark Theme.

Account settings are ok:

No contrast theme

No dark Windows Theme


Compare with my setting in Options > General: My Office Background is Circuit and my Office Theme is "Use system setting". You could also delete/rename Normal.dotm and launch Word to re-create it as default.

@harrymc Sometimes after changing theme settings back & forth it seems to be working, but whatever I do, it always returns to black background after a restart. Even after deleting the normal.dotm

A brute-force method would be to uninstall Office and reinstall.

yeah, I'm giving it another day to maybe find a solution before trying a complete reinstall.

Even enable Dark Mode, the background in Styles of Word will not change. I suggest you change the Windows theme for a check.
